# Proxied websocket connection is immediately closed

Tags: node.js, websocket, create-react-app, http-proxy-middleware

I have a create-react-app dev server proxying backend connections (as one does).  Suddenly websocket proxying stopped working.

My setupProxy.js looks like this:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  const port = process.env.BACKEND_PORT || '8080';
  const target = `http://localhost:${port}`;
  app.use(proxy(['/path/to/socket'], {
    target,
    ws: true,
    onProxyReqWs: function(proxyReq, req, socket) {
      socket.on('error', err => console.log(err));
      console.log('socket is destroyed', socket.destroyed)
    },
    logLevel: 'debug',
  }));

  app.use(proxy(shouldProxy, {
    target,
    logLevel: 'debug',
  }));
```

(where `shouldProxy` is a function, since my logic for when to proxy is... non-trivial).

When the browser (Firefox 71 or Chrome 79) creates a websocket connection, I can see that the backend gets the request and responds normally, but the browser gets a 400 Bad request and the dev-server console has this:

```
[HPM] GET /path/to/socket -> http://localhost:8080
socket is destroyed true
[HPM] Upgrading to WebSocket
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:321:17)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> ([...]/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/passes/ws-incoming.js:143:14)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:305:20)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:508:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:305:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:341:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:316:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:250:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED'
}
[HPM] Client disconnected
```

So *something* seems to be destroying the socket very early in the proxying process, but I cannot fathom what.

I currently run with node 13.5.0, http-proxy 1.18.0 and http-proxy-middleware 0.20.0; I've tried downgrading node to 12.14.0 and HPM to 0.19.1, to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [an issue with create-react-app 3.3.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8094), caused by [this bug in webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2310).  Adding `"webpack-dev-server": "3.10.1"` to the `resolutions` section of `package.json` and `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to `.env` fixed it.